# Lock Picklist Field After a Record is Created

Tags: picklist, validation-rule

What would be the best solution in order to lock a picklist field after a record is created?

Scenario: Upon new Lead creation, users choose a picklist value for the Lead Source field. Once the record is created, the user should not have the ability to edit the Lead Source field.

Comment: You can either write a validation to prevent users from changing value OR create a new layout and a record type named (Read only) and mark the field Lead Source as read only on this new page layout. When the record is created, flip the record type from the one you are using now to this new record type.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you pretend (only be able to select the Lead Source once the record is created) you can use the ISCHANGED function.

Please find below the formula to prevent the Lead Source from being changed after record creation:

```
ISCHANGED(LeadSource)
```

Best regards!